# How i can set banner role with user input?

Tags: python, discord.py

There is my code:

```
@Bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_role(ctx,role:discord.Role):
    global global_ban 
    global_ban = role

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_role(global_ban)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

When i start the bot terminal gives that error:

```
    @commands.has_role(global_ban)
NameError: name 'global_ban' is not defined
```

Comment: You have to set the role like this: `@commands.has_role("global_ban")` if you want to go by name.

Comment: @Dominik i want to set role name with command

Comment: `global_ban` must then be a function or similar

Comment: @Dominik, indeed, but once the role is set it cannot be changed. Unless that's what OP wants